# Rectangular prism with volume and surface area

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, solid-geometry

Here is the question:
A rectangular prism has a volume of $720$ cm$^3$ and a surface area of $666$ cm$^2$. If the lengths of all its edges are integers, what is the length of the longest edge?

This is from a previously timed competition. Quick answers will be the most helpful.

You can set up equations and use Vieta's formulas to get $x^3+bx^2+333x-720$.
How do I solve the problem after this?

Comment: “This is from a timed competition. Fast answers are best”. Would that no be cheating then?

Comment: @JackLeGrüß This is from 2011, why would I cheat

Comment: @JackLeGrüß There are many timed competitions, such as AMC. Have you ever even participated in one?

Comment: @AndrewChin  Please post answer in answer fields, and not in comments.

Comment: @chem1kal: I was enquiring from you,..., not telling you. (No, I have not participated before).

Comment: @chem1kal  Your phrasing: "fast answers are best" could easily be interpreted as you need a fast answer because you are taking a test.

Comment: @amWhy Well then that's on me. I meant that quick answers would be good (like 1 or 2 min answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$xyz=720$$ and $$xy+xz+yz=333,$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are naturals.

Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$720\geq z^3,$$ which gives $$1\leq z\leq8$$ and $z=3$ is valid, which gives $x=16$ and $y=15.$

Answer (score 0):

Factorize $720$ as a product of three factors, then pairwise, their products sum to $333$. Once you see this, you know that two of the factors must be odd.

From trial and error, I get the longest side to be $16$, with the other two sides being $3$ and $15$.  Verifying:

$$3\times15\times16=720,\qquad 2\times(3\times15+15\times16+16\times3)=666.$$